# How to secure non-consumable in-app purchases when user logs in

Tags: android, ios, google-cloud-firestore, in-app-purchase

In one of my apps, users can unlock the full version through non-consumable in-app purchase. In the next update, I am introducing an ability to log in to our app so that their progress can be synced across their devices.

Now comes the problem - when the user logs in, I will transfer the information about their purchase to our server. However, what happens if a user logs out from our app, and then their friend logs in? The device is still connected to the App Store using the original Apple ID, and they can restore the purchase which will now be associated with their friend's account.

As you can see, theoretically users can allow all their friends to unlock our app for free unless we find a way of uniquely associating each purchase with a particular user on our servers.

I am sure this is a common issue, so how does it usually get tackled? We need to secure purchases originating from iOS and Android.

P.S. The syncing is done via Firestore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "official" guidance on this from either of the App Stores. What we do at [RevenueCat](https://www.revenuecat.com/) is save the receipt file against a user Id, then whenever a new purchase (or restore) comes in check if the receipt file is already saved to another userId. We can then return an error that this receipt is already in use by another account.

If you look at some of the big subscriptions apps (Netflix, Spotify, HBO, etc.) you'll notice they don't even have a "Restore Purchases" button. You can get away with this if you require an account sign-in since purchases can be restored by signing into your account. However, unless you have engineering and customer support teams like Netflix, a "Restore Purchases" button is generally a good idea as it can save you from edge cases - just check if the receipt is already on file for another account before "unlocking" access.

Comment: Do you store the whole file or just the originalTransactionID? I thought that ID will be sufficient.

Comment: The originalTransactionID is sufficient for this use-case. Probably worth storing the entire receipt file, you may want it for something else down the road.